# Distinct Query For CursorLoader

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-cursorloader

I am using CursorLoader to populate my listView. 
But I need to get distinct result set. 
But CursorLoader has no constructor to set distinct parameter.

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes!

In the CursorLoader constructor you specify a URI.  Part of that URI is the ContentProvider Authority.  The rest, though, is up to you!  So create a virtual table!

If you have a table "songbirds", perhaps your URI is:

```
content://my.content.provider/songbirds
```

Simply teach your ContentProvider (add one more clause to your `UriMatcher`) to recognize the URI:

```
content://my.content.provider/distinctSongbirds
```

Process the "distinct" URI exactly as you do the non-distinct one, except add a "distinct" param to the actual DB query, when you make it.

Comment: I see what you mean. Thanks A lot. Now, subtitles of my list view requires complex subquery which i might not be able to get from main query. Can I use MergeCursor for that? or is there any easier way to do it?

Comment: I don't know your use case, but I would think that you could use the virtual table trick for just about anything you need to do...

Comment: I managed to apply your concept. But irony is I ran into a paradox. The projection parameter i am passing requires _id column otherwise it throws an error saying _id column is not provided. But when i am providing _id column it is no longer unique any more because distinct operator is now counting the _id column as well. I am wondering when you say virtual table did you mean just to have a different case in UriMatcher and have a different query builder? or Literally create some short of table or view on the fly. Note: I am using CursorLoader,CursorAdapter and ContentProvider.Thanks again :)

Comment: Yep.  That's a separate problem.  In your SQL query, add SELECT rownum as _id, ....

Comment: Actually, the suggestion above won't work.  ...but something like this will:  "SELECT min(rownum) as _id, somecol FROM sometable GROUP BY somecol"

Comment: Can't see any other way.  Appreciate  That :)